# Ubuntu dock changes version/style intermittently

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3. I am used to the dock in the left hand picture. However, sometimes I get the right hand picture instead. The right hand one automatically hides. I'd like to only see the left.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When your dock changes, you may hit "Alt"+"F2", input "r" (without the quotes) and hit "Enter" to restart the shell. Most likely this will repair it.

Comment: Do you by any chance have Dash to Dock extension installed?

Comment: @pomsky apparently, but not intentionally `gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock/bionic,bionic 63-1 all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing in the [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62uLr.png) (right one) is not actually the dock, but the [GNOME dash](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities). The dash is a default feature of GNOME Shell, it appears *only* in *Activities* (and applications) overview. Ubuntu Dock (package name: `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`) is a GNOME shell extension that turns the dash into a fully-fledged dock that may appear always. 
Presumably you're seeing the second screenshot sometimes when the Ubuntu Dock extension is failing to load properly for some reason.

As a temporary workaround either rebbot your system (or log out and log in again) or simply restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing `r`, and finally hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.